# Laravel Form submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

how can i submit a lararvel form  with jquery (not ajax) but simple post with data(object or array) and retrieve this data  for the method in the controller

```
var index = 0;
var seance = [];
$( "#addSession" ).click(function() 
{
  var session_name = $('#session_name').val();
  var session_description = $('#session_description').val();
  var session_lieu = $('#session_name').val();
  var session_date = $('#session_date').val();
  if(seance[session_date])
  {
    index ++;
    seance[session_date][index]= [];
    seance[session_date][index]['name']= session_name;
  }
  else
  {
    seance[session_date] = [];
    seance[session_date][index]= [];
    seance[session_date][index]['name']= session_name;
  }
  console.log(seance);
});


$( '#form-create-event' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        /* how to add seance to data submitted with the form and how can i get it from the controller  */
        console.log('submitted');
        /*e.preventDefault();*/
        console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (without using some hacky tricks) is to use a XMLhttpRequest that will send a POST request with your form and your custom data into it. To do this, you can use this $ajax object from jQuery. You can look at the exemple by W3School : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: thank's for help i tried this method, but when i try to get data via $request->data i get an empty object {}

Comment: Normaly, if your request is à POST request, you can access the data by the `$_POST` php variable (e.g. `$_POST["name"]`